# Adding an element id with coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am writing a class in coffescript and am able to add a class name with the following:

```
class Str extends Spine.Controller

  className: 'myClass'

module.exports = Str
```

This outputs a div with the class 'myClass'. But how do I assign an element id??? I'm basically trying to output the following:

```
<div id="myId" class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: you can first use getElementByTag method to get the element, and then  set the element id

Comment: There is no context given in your question. How CoffeeScript class relates to div element?